# Node JS Express all requests showing 404

Tags: javascript, node.js

All requests are showing `GET / 404 8.128 ms-13` in console.

I have posted the code below, there is no error in the code. I can run other `NodeJS` applications. But this is showing 404 in console. It is not even showing the fav icon. It worked once showing `Cannot GET /` error and the fav icon was visible at that time.

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8001;
var four0four = require('./utils/404')();
var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/favicon.ico'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes'));
console.log('About to crank up node');
console.log('PORT=' + port);
console.log('NODE_ENV=' + environment);
switch (environment){        
default:
    console.log('** DEV **');
    app.use(express.static('./src/client/'));
    app.use(express.static('./'));
    app.use(express.static('./tmp'));
    app.use('/app/*', function(req, res, next) {
        four0four.send404(req, res);
    });
    app.use('/*', express.static('./src/client/index.html'));
    break;
}
app.listen(port, function() {
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
console.log('env = ' + app.get('env') +
            '\n__dirname = ' + __dirname  +
            '\nprocess.cwd = ' + process.cwd());
});
```

Comment: what is your `four0four.send404(req, res);`, you placed it as your middleware

Comment: Are you adding `/api` before your routes?

Comment: @BidhanA I am not aware of this, Actually I am new to NodeJS

Answer (score 1):

According to http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html I think that your route here `app.use('/*', express.static('./src/client/index.html'));` will use `./src/client/index.html` as the base path and append whatever you provide to find a file. For example

`/some-file` will look for `./src/client/index.html/some-file` which is obviously not existed

In case you want to understand it more, the static middleware use https://github.com/pillarjs/send internally to stream file

So you can do this
`app.use('/*', express.static('./src/client'));`

It will, by default, set `/` to `src/client/index.html`, you can change that behaviour by setting `index` option as specified here https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static

If you want to redirect `/*` to `./src/client/index.html` do this

```
// first set the static middleware
app.use('/public', express.static('./src/client'));
// then use redirect
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('/public/index.html');
});
```

This setup will redirect everything to `public/index.html`. If you want to add APIs or other routes, put it before the `app.get('/*')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting a redirect in console when I replaced the switch code with your code `GET /public/index.html 302 0.498 ms-92`. In browser I am getting `Internet Explorer cannot display the page`

Comment: Even if i hit 127.0.0.1:8001, I am getting 404 error, Any idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: It is showing the `website has a redirect loop` in chrome

Comment: What are you trying to do? Redirect everything to `public/index.html`? btw, I changed `app.use` to `app.get`, my old code was wrong. It should work now, I have just run it in my machine

Comment: I am actually new to Node JS. What I need is a just a server to run my javascript code. I have replaced the code in the Switch Default. When I run it, I am getting the `redirect 302` loop, I guess.